# How do I change a button value to an image on click

Tags: jquery

I have this button and when I click it I want the text inside it to change to an image. What I have now isn't working, any ideas?

```
<%= submit_tag 'CREATE MYMANUAL', class: 'submit', id: "generate" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#generate').on("click", function(){
    $('#generate').val("ajax-loader.gif")
});
</script>
```

Comment: $('#generate').hide().after('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />");

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you hide it first & then insert the image in its place (potentially replacing the button)?
If the `ajax-loader` is not a button, you can easily make loaderbutton gif

```
$('#generate').hide().after('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />")
```

EDIT - Probably a better solution

```
$('#generate').val('');//empty button text
$('#generate').css('background-image','url(ajax-loader.gif)'); //add loading gif as background image
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid HTML.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_src.asp).  I believe you have to use an input of type "image", with a src set to your image URL.  You would have to either remove the button and add and input of type "image" like this:

```
$('#generate').click(function() {
  var $par = $(this).parent();
  $(this).remove();
  $parent.append("<input type='image' src='my.gif' />")
});
```

or see if you could flip the type on the fly:
    $('#generate').click(function() {
      $(this).attr("type","image");
      $(this).attr("src","my.gif");
    });

Not sure if the second one would work, though.